# ImportError: cannot import name 'count_params' from 'keras.utils'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am attempting to run the code below.

```
from DataGeneratorSimCLR import DataGeneratorSimCLR as DataGenerator
from SimCLR import SimCLR
```

I am getting the error...

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'count_params' from 'keras.utils'
```

I have tried using a few different versions of Keras and using tensorflow format that is mentioned in a few other similar questions.

As I am not sure if this is a syntax, setup, or version problem I have also included a possibly relevant picture of my workspace on Google Colab below. Please let me know if there is any more information I should provide.

[image]

Comment: Please include your code and error as text and not as an image.

Comment: keras is just so confusing.  might be just https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/summary_utils.py#L19  (so ```from keras.utils.summary_utils import count_params```).  I had originally  thought https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/layer_utils.py#L86 but it your code isn't with tensorflow.

Comment: You need to [install correct versions of the libraries.](https://github.com/mwdhont/SimCLRv1-keras-tensorflow/blob/master/requirements.txt)

Comment: I accidentally pasted the error twice into my question. I have edited it now with the code I was running Sorry about that. I tried installing the libraries mentioned in the requirements folder and still get the error message. summary_utils was not recognized either.